# xCode Single Database Row JSON Parsing

Tags: php, json, xcode

I have a php page that returns the following information: -

[{"ID":"1234ABCD","name":"Terry Tate","gender":"M"}]

I would like to pull this in to xCode and parse it. All the tutorials I have seen are very complicated and seem to be geared towards pulling multiple records from a database. It's not the complexity that concerns me, I just don't want to write unnecessary code. So I was wondering if there's an easier and faster way to do this without having to setup all the connection protocols such as didRecieveData, connectionDidFinishLoading etc. and what are the risk of not going down that route?

Currently I'm using this code to retrieve the data: -

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.testServer.com/getData.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *body = [@"uID=1234ABCD" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  // not necessary, but good practice

NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // use the data/error/response objects here
    if (data) {
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"responseString = %@", responseString);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
        NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
    }
}];
[task resume];
```